# EXTJS: Uncaught ReferenceError: Dexie is not defined at myJavascriptFile.js:18

Tags: extjs, local-storage, indexeddb, dexie

I am swapping out one IndexedDb wrapper(localForage) for another(Dexie) and I am unable to run the application because the recommended way to integrate it within the ExtJs framework is not working for me. What have I done wrong?

My current version/s of ExtJs: 
  framework: 6.6.0.258
  Cmd: v6.6.0.13
  Dexie version is latest

The Dexie documentation recommends that you set up your database like this

```
 var db = new Dexie("MyDatabase");
     db.version(1).stores({
        myStoreName, "++id, indexOne, indexTwo",
        myOtherStoreName, "++id, indexOne, indexTwo",
     });
```

myExtJsFile.js

```
   Ext.define('DataLayer.Inferface', {
      extend: 'Ext.Component',
      xtype: 'DLInterface',
      config: {
          stuff...
        db: new Dexie("mydatabaseName"),
      }
```

The way that the ExtJs documentation recommends using an external library is to reference it in the app.json file in the js array

app.json

```
"js": [
   {
     "path": "${framework.dir}/build/ext-all-rtl-debug.js"
   },
   {
     "path": "dexie.js"     //Dexie is located in the same folder as app.json
   },
```

I get a successful build yet when I go to deploy it(run locally) I get the run-time error listed in the title of this question. I am aware that the intellisense in VSCode isn't working all that good, so I didn't really think much of it when I was not appearing to have access to the global Dexie object. 
  I have tried several different ways, and places to load this library with m=no luck. I would use a CDN, but it is an offline capable app so I really want the library locally. How should I be getting, referencing, and using 3rd party libraries in Ext?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

If You use external library in Ext.define, try to include external libraries before extjs libraries (`ext-all-rtl-debug.js`, `app.js` etc.).

Another solution - don`t attach remote libraries on class defines - use initialize/initComponent instead. Example:

```
Ext.define('DataLayer.Inferface', {
extend: 'Ext.Component',
xtype: 'DLInterface',
config: {
    stuff...
},
initComponent: function () {
    this.db=new Dexie("mydatabaseName");
    this.callParent(arguments);
}
```